# Why I don't success to output simple js algorithem?

Tags: javascript

the user need to write the name of the animal, and I need to output the name+animalCode connected.
For some reason I am not getting any output.

Here is the code:

```js
var str = "Cow12,Dog3,Cat721,Lion532";
var getInput = document.getElementById("inp1");
var getSubmit = document.getElementById("subm1");

getSubmit.onclick = function() {
  var input = getInput;
  var firstPlace = str.indexOf(input);
  var numPlace = str.indexOf(",", firstPlace);
  var newWord = str.slice(firstPlace, numPlace);

  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = newWord;
};
```

```html
<form> 
  <input id="inp1" type="text">
  <input id="subm1" type="submit">
</form>

<p id="print"></p>
```

Thank you very much for the help ! :)

Comment: Remove action part from the form tag.

Comment: Yeah it was my mistake, I edited the question. Still don't work. @PrabhjotSinghKainth

Comment: @lirsim what should I be inputting into the form exactly and what should be the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the `.value` part.

```js
var str = "Cow12,Dog3,Cat721,Lion532";
var getInput = document.getElementById("inp1");
var getSubmit = document.getElementById("subm1");

getSubmit.onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input = getInput.value;
  var firstPlace = str.indexOf(input);
  var numPlace = str.indexOf(",", firstPlace);
  var newWord = str.slice(firstPlace, numPlace);

  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = newWord;
};
```

```html
<form> 
  <input id="inp1" type="text">
  <input id="subm1" type="submit">
</form>

<p id="print"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change :

Remove form tag as there is no need for that.

```js
var str = "Cow12,Dog3,Cat721,Lion532";
function getSubmit() 
{
var input =  document.getElementById("inp1").value;
var firstPlace = str.indexOf("",input);
var numPlace = str.indexOf(",", firstPlace);
var newWord = str.slice(firstPlace, numPlace);
document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = newWord;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp1" type="text">
<button id="subm1" onclick="getSubmit()">Submit</button>
<p id="print"></p>
```

Comment: I need it only in external js file. Prevent deafult will help ? If so, can you show me how to do it in alogorithem ?